# Running several commands in a screen-split

Tags: gnu-screen, tmux

I have a few long running commands that I would like to run together in the same screen (same tab in the terminal app).

My current setup is like this:

```
tmux new-session -d 'cmd1'
tmux split-window 'cmd2'
tmux split-window 'cmd3'
tmux attach
```

However, it seems that `tmux split-window` actually splits the last split, so if I run several command this way, the first command gets half the screen, and the other commands get progressively smaller and smaller parts.

Is there a simpler way that runs all commands in equal-sized splits?

Comment: not sure if tmux does the same thing as terminator, but if it does check that out, it's brilliant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just add the following command before your `tmux attach`

```
tmux select-layout even-vertical
```

Comment: +1 for turning around and sharing what you just learned :)